# Unable to view the log files in localhost browsing HDFS

Tags: hadoop, twitter

I have successfully started the `flume-agent` but can't view the log files in `HDFS`.

The path I have set in `twitter.conf` is:

```
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:9000/user/flume/tweets/
```

Please help me to get rid of this error and view the data in my `HDFS`.

Comment: You will see the error in logs directory of Flume. Try to solve it yourself and if your can't then update your question with it.

Comment: Did you find anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set your `hadoop home` in `.bashrc` as

```
export HADOOP_HOME=<Path to your hadoop home>
```

Then you don't need `localhost:9000` in the following

```
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:9000/user/flume/tweets/
```

So the correct line should be

```
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs:///user/flume/tweets/
```

It should work given that your twitter.conf is as below

```
    # Naming the components on the current agent. 
    TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter 
    TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel 
    TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS

    # Describing/Configuring the source 
    TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource
    TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = Your OAuth consumer key
    TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = Your OAuth consumer secret 
    TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = Your OAuth consumer key access token 
    TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = Your OAuth consumer key access token secret 
    TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = tutorials point,java, bigdata, mapreduce, mahout, hbase, nosql

    # Describing/Configuring the sink 

    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs 
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs:///user/flume/tweets/
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream 
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text 
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0 
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10000 

    # Describing/Configuring the channel TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory 
    TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10000 
    TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 100

    # Binding the source and sink to the channel 
    TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel 

    TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type=memory
```

And your command should be similar to the following in `Flume` home

```
bin/flume-ng agent --conf ./conf/ -f conf/twitter.conf Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n itterAgent
```

You can check [Tutorials Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_flume/fetching_twitter_data.htm) for better understanding

**Note : You can always debug the errors by looking for exact errors in `flume.log` in logs directory of flume**